# Android - How to replace string tag in spannableStringBuilder

Tags: java, android, regex

It's fine? :D

I have an API PHP that receives html text replaced by string [tag] tags and my Android app needs to replace this tags of text by Spannable strings.

I have a problem with replace string tags of `[strong]`, `[br]`, `[p]`, `[i]` to `SpannableString` and to apprimorate the content text.

Not all text is overwritten correctly. Some [strong] tags, for example, still remain there, other times the text is repeated, rather than overlapping.

My Activity receives that:

```java
...

SpannableStringBuilder parseContent = new StringTagParserHelper(tagPost.getContent())
    .addMultipleStyle();

contentView.setText(parseContent);
```

My String parser classe is:

```java
public class StringTagParserHelper {

    private static String rawText;
    private SpannableStringBuilder spannableContent;

    public StringTagParserHelper(String text) {
        rawText = text;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public SpannableStringBuilder addMultipleStyle() {
        spannableContent = new SpannableStringBuilder(rawText);

        cleanTags("strong");

        return spannableContent;
    }

    private void cleanTags(String tag) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(tag + "\\](.+?)\\[/" + tag);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rawText);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            Log.d("PARSE", String.valueOf(matcher.group(1)));

            String _internal = matcher.group(1);
            int start = matcher.start();
            int end = matcher.end();

            if (tag.equals("strong")) {
                Spannable spanText = new SpannableString(_internal);
                spanText.setSpan(
                        new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, _internal.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                );

                spannableContent.replace(start, end, spanText);
            }

            if (tag.equals("br")) {
                //
            }

        }
    }
```

.

[EDIT]

Added 2 screenshots.

- One with bold text and spannable replace of `spanText`

[image]

- another without style and spannable replace `_internal` string.

[image]

The line of `Log.d()` receives the list of raw string text without tags.

`Log.d("PARSE", String.valueOf(matcher.group(1)));`

Please, help me, guys!

**References:**

[Android TextView format multiple words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973764/android-textview-format-multiple-words)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560685/3332734

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369427/3332734

[Android. Replace * character from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590710/android-replace-character-from-string)

Comment: Maybe because of newlines in between, try compiling with `Pattern.DOTALL`. Another thing is that there may be nested tags, then you cannot do that with regex.

Comment: Don't work! Okay, but for now I need to solve this tags problem. I'm ignoring that there are nested tags.

Comment: I added 2 screenshots and more details.

Comment: Try using this regex instead [`\\[p\\](.*?)\\[/p\\]`](https://regex101.com/r/ISnOcw/2), the opening bracket is included in the tag

Comment: It's not work. Some phrases containing `[strong] words here [/ strong]` are not replaced. Bold phrases have not been replaced correctly. Maybe because regex deleted each tag and changed the position of words.

Comment: How could solve this problem? I could not find anything like it on the internet.